# Are my md5 keys actually different? Do I have to redownload Ubuntu?

Tags: md5sum

I have downloaded the ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64 Ubuntu version, I just did the md5sum check from the Windiws command prompt and had `414f5d28b2ac85d0e7aaf969f9bd0cb5` as a return.

As far as the md5 key given here is http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/comment_verifier_l_integrite_de_son_image_cd#liste_des_empreintes_md5
is `cab6dd5ee6d649ed1b24e807c877c0ae` does it mean I have to re-download it again?

Should I even delete the existing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you got that right. You have to redownload it in order to get an image you can be sure to be safe.

If you have a low bandwidth and/or a lot of connection drops, I recommend downloading it using a BitTorrent client. The BitTorrent protocol features automated error correction; the defective chunks are redownloaded automatically, so you don't have to start all over.

You can get the torrent file from the [Alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) page. As a torrent client, I can recommend [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) for Windows or Mac OS X, or [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) for Mac OS X and Linux, but there are many other clients available.

Comment: Okay. 30 minutes wasted. But I will make it!
God, I thought the sites you're talking were places not to go like the Bois-de-Boulogne in Paris!

Comment: The softwares @the_Seppi is talking about are totally legit, and (as for the bois-de-boulogne) what matters depends what you do with (or when you're there ;-)

Comment: Yes, BitTorrent seems to have a rather bad reputation, as it's often used to illegally share copyright protected contents. However, as @arainone pointed out, the BT network itself is no evil and certainly is very useful.